# Symfony2: Merge 2 forms in single page with different bootstrap tab

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have two entities : Content and Synopsis.

Content is related with synopsis with `oneToOne` relationship and persisted by content ID.

After generating entity and form I have two controller for ContentController and Synopsis Controller, along with two from class. ContentType and SynopsisType.

Here I am facing two problems:

1. I want content and synopsis creation should be done from one page that is content/new.. I am using bootstrap tab form content and synopsis
2. In synopsis I see there is a dropdown for selecting content name which is related to this synopsis. I need to pass the content id hiddenly when creating content and synopsis but as they are two different entity I couldnt find a clue how to do that

How can i achieve my goal?

ORM of my relation:

<kbd>Content.orm.yml</kbd>

```
 oneToOne:
    synopsis:
        targetEntity: Synopsis
        mappedBy: content
        cascade:
              - persist
```

<kbd>Synopsis.orm.yml</kbd>

```
oneToOne:
    content:
        targetEntity: Content
        inversedBy: synopsis
        joinColumn:
             name: content_id
             referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: Have a look at [`How to Embed a Collection of Forms`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: hi I already checked that but my scenario is bit different the example is oneToMany relation ship

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you don't want to choose "**content**" at all from a dropdown?

Comment: Yes as they will be in one form so the current content id will be placed in synopsis's content_id field

Answer (score 0):

You can use entity field (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) to embed content field in a synopsis form

Comment: just checked that but its for radio, select, check, i need to use textbox this is what i did:

->add('brief_english','entity',array('class'=> 'BbdBongoAppBundle:Synopsis', 'property'=>'brief_english'))

but nothing is showing

Comment: If you want to allow editing of a field of Content type inside a Synopsis form, then use embedded forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms